# Functional data analysis references

Tags: assumptions, iid, functional-data-analysis

I am working on a inferential framework for functional data. I have categorical independent variables and a functional response variables. Different implementations of functional linear models are producing good results, but I would like to test for error correlation. I read the papers of [Chiou and Muller](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947306002465)  and [Gabrys et al.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227369247_Tests_for_Error_Correlation_in_the_Functional_Linear_Model), but they just mentioned models with functional variables on both sides. Does anyone know of any papers/methods about the error assumption in function-on-scalar models?